# Как получить URL посещённых ресурсов?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Всем привет.

Идея следующая: есть расширение Chrome, оно передаёт все посещённые URL на сервер, каждый пользователь имеет свой id. Можно, конечно, использовать Историю браузера, но этот подход не гибкий. Каким образом можно реализовать подобное? Интересует коллегиальное решение, как общая концепция, так и технологии для реализации. Сам Java и  С++ developer, в WEB только въезжаю, поэтому, может, вопрос глуповат-). Но прошу отнестись с пониманием.

Спасибо.

PS Это не инструмент слежки, необходимо для исследования.

Answer (score 3):

> Можно, конечно, использовать Историю браузера, но этот подход не гибкий.

Вполне гибкий. Хром предоставляет специальный API для работы с историей просмотров - это [chrome.history](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html). Там же есть [ссылка](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/history/) на пример работы с API.

Можно создать расширение, которое будет работать всегда, когда запущен Хром, и периодически (скажем, раз в день) в определенное время извлекать историю просмотров, прошедших с последней активации расширения, анализировать их и отсылать данные на сервер.

Comment: Нормальное решение, если вам не подходит этот вариант, тогда делайте локальный прокси, который будет этим заниматься.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - опять же [расширение для хрома](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) которое будет при каждой загрузке страницы отправлять серверу текущий урл и id пользователя (id можно хранить в [localStorage](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html)).
На сервере анализировать урл и писать его в базу привязывая к пользователю с указанным id.